# Who maps files to memory if I do not use MemoryMappedFile

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-mapped-files

I had to work with lists of objects like they are in memory, but all data is persisted on disk. Something like memory mapped files, but instead I decided to make some wrapper which implements `IList`, but all functions just read/write file stream. i.e (locks/etc code is skipped)

```
public DiskMappedList(string directory)
{
    _count = 0;

    if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
    }
    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    _fileStreamHandle = File.Create(Path.Combine(directory, fileName));
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.PrepareSerializer<T>();
}

public void Add(T item)
{
        ProtoBuf.Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(_fileStreamHandle, item, _lengthPrefix, _fieldNum);
        _fileStreamHandle.Flush();
        _count++;
}
```

Notice that I use simple `FileStream` which is open by `File.Open` and that stream is closed only when object is removed from memory.

Despite fact that only handle resides in memory I see high memory usage. RamMap shows that a big portion of files is "Memory mapped file". 
So the question is - if I do not use MMF api and file is loaded into memory only when I call `ToList()`, which is pretty rare, who maps all my files to memory? Or may be "Memory mapped files" region is not for MMF only? Or may be `FileStream` uses MMF internally? Why I see several Gb memory usage?

PS: Some screenshots
[image]
[image]

Comment: `File.Open` doesn't memory map a file.

Comment: DLLs are memory mapped. Maybe that?

Comment: I know, but why all those files are memory mapped then?  I thought that may be windows search indexing does that so I turned off context indexing for disk, but still.. And no, those are not dlls but my files

Comment: Are you trying to say that your data file in this case is showing as being memory mapped? Or that there are a lot of memory mapped files?

Comment: Step through this, before the call you post note the memory use and again after. I doubt that your file is what is taking up memory.

Comment: Exactly that my data files are showing as being memory mapped. Not dlls, not event logs, but my files which I create from code

Comment: Can you show us the code where you open the file.

Comment: Have added constructor code and screenshots. All those files with guids - are my data files

Comment: You are not read/write files from/to disk. You are read/write them from/to operation system buffer. Which, as far as I understand, is essentially memory mapped.

Comment: That is a part of question. I couldn't find any information on system internals, normally it is a comparison MMF vs Streams but nowhere it is said that streams are memory mapped also.

Comment: From the docs: "for definitions of the labels RAMMap uses as well as to learn about the physical-memory allocation algorithms used by the Windows memory manager, please see [Windows Internals, 5th Edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/learn/windows-internals)". I don't have my copy handy here. If I had to guess I'd say all the file system cache also falls under "mapped files", since it has no separate tag for that. Then every file access that's not uncached would also end up here, even if you didn't map the file explicitly.

Comment: Yes, it looks like file system cache with LargeSystemCache in effect, but I don't have that book to confirm it.

Comment: Do you ever `.Close` the file?

Comment: >>stream is closed only when object is removed from memory.
I want to keep it open since there may be write each several seconds while 1 read in hour

Comment: "File Summary" shows you the contents of the OS cache. When you close a file that file internally stays open as part of the cache. The OS file cache is based on memory mappings.